# python: Find matching tuples in the list

Tags: python, list, tuples, integer-hashing

What is the quickest way to find matching 2-tuples in another list of 2-tuples?

The following codes looks extremely inefficient.
loc1 and loc2 are list of tuples of (x,y) coordinates.

```
loc3=[]
for loc in loc1:
    if loc in loc2:
        loc3.append(loc)
```

I think hashing is the key but not sure how to do it on Python.
Please teach me an elegant code. 
Thanks.

Comment: You are completely right that a hashing is the key. And fortunately, Python makes that easy with the built-in `set` and `dict` classes, built around hash tables. So, mgilson's answer is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use sets and `intersection`:

```
loc3 = set(loc1).intersection(loc2)
```

This gives you a `set` which is unordered and won't contain duplicates (and enforces that the items are hashable).  If that's a problem, see the other answer by Phil Frost.  However, this should be significantly more efficient where order and duplicates are unnecessary.

A order preserving solution which can contain duplicates, but requires hashability of the items (in `loc2`) is as follows:

```
sloc2 = set(loc2)
loc3 = [ item for item in loc1 if item in sloc2 ]  #still O(m)
```

In python, a `set` is simply a hash table.  Checking to see if an item is contained in that set is an (approximately) O(1) operation because the position of the item is found via hashing.

Comment: +1 - you can also use this: `loc3 = list(set(loc1) & set(loc2))`.

Comment: @Tadeck -- Yeah, that's completely correct, but that requires building an extra `set` :).  And I prefer `intersection` as it feels more explicit to me.

Comment: Generator expressions / generators are another solution with different time / space costs.

Comment: +1. I didn't realize you had the second version in your answer now, and wasted time writing the same answer… Anyway, it might be worth explaining that a `set` is a hash table, and checking `item in sloc2` just requires hashing `item`, so it's exactly what the OP knew he wanted but didn't know how to do in Python.